req.files might be undefined
I have setup a typescript project with multer. The app should act as a REST API that will be responsible for file uploads. When I place upload.array('files', 10) as my middleware in app.post(), the file(s) are properly uploaded to the specified directory. But when I try to interface with them inside the callback of the POST request, things don't really add up. First of all, when I try to console.log(req.files[0]) for the first file in the array, it gives the error req.files might be undefined. This can be fixed by doing it like that:
if (req.files !== undefined)
{
    console.log(req.files[0]);
}

When doing that however, it gives the following error:
Element implicitly has an any type because expression of type 0 can't be used to index type { [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[]
I can suppress this error with //@ts-ignore and it does work, but that's really not how i want to do this because that way it's pretty much doomed to fail at some point. What exactly am i missing here that makes it not work?
My upload looks like this:
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'files/');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

export default upload;


try How to properly handle req.files in node post request using multer and typescript

@traynor thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for. Can you post that as an answer so i can mark this as resolved?

I'd just be duplicating the linked answer.. upvoted linked post instead
